# Execute javascript developed in node.js from jmeter jsr223 post processor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, blazemeter

i have a javascript code written in node.js (VS Code), how to place it in jsr223 post processer.

Comment: can i add some node.js jar in lib/ext and run the script, please share links to jar files.  @Blazemeter  are you planning on some code convertors like beanshell to groovy or javascript to groovy

Answer (score 2):

Java and Node.js are different beasts and cannot be easily integrated.

The options are in:

1. Execute your Node.js scripts using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) like you would do from a terminal/command prompt
2. Re-write your Node.js code in [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) as it's the [only recommended scripting language for JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) as of now
3. Consider using [J2V8](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2016/07/20/running-node-js-on-the-jvm/) for your code invocation if it's complex and either cannot be easily converted to Groovy or suitable for command-line execution.